# Why does a Landsat 8 band not load into QGIS SCP plugin?

Tags: qgis-plugins, landsat-8

A 2015 Landsat 8 band 2 does not load into QGIS' Semi-automatic Classification Plugin window when wanting to clip multiple raster bands.

[image]
Bands are loaded from Table of Contents (TOC) as displayed above or clicking 'Refresh list'. The TOC (below) shows band 2 but, it does not appear in the SCP list. Years 2013 and 2014 do not give this problem.

2015 bands in TOC:
[image]

Comment: Are you adding bands from the Map Canvas? From File? Please write your operations that lead you to this, as it might be either a bug/system error or some user error.

Comment: @HDunn, question was updated.

Answer (score 2):

After pansharpening the satellite images I had to convert to WGS84 coordinate system. The first attempt caused something to go wrong in the reprojected band 2 GeoTIFF file.

When I performed the reprojection a second time, the band 2 was listed in the "Clip Multipple Rasters" list. Obviously a glitch of some sorts.

Comment: The SCP does have some glitches with loading bands. If you see one persist, you can contact Luca Congedo on his FB group, he's more than happy to help and receive bug reports. https://www.facebook.com/groups/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/